# Sequence & Class Diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm pretty familiar with UML 2.0, I used it many times, nonetheless I still face some problems understanding some details.
For in instance, in Sequence Diagram, I still don't know when to use a synchronous message and when to use an asynchronous.
As for Class Diagram, I have some serious problems knowing when to use a composition/aggregation and association.
If someone possible illustrates that with concrete examples that would be great.

Comment: You should split that in two questions and elaborate what your concerns are or your question might get closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sequence diagrams

A synchronous message is the equivalent of a function call. The processing is performed synchronously (sic) and the result of the processing is known when the function returns.

An asynchronous message is the equivalent of posting a mail. The message will potentially be put in a queue and processed later on, possibly by another thread. The result of the processing may not be available when the call returns.

For high-level diagrams (use cases, architecture, ...), you might consider the distinction as irrelevant.

## Class diagrams

Associations, aggregations and compositions are linked to ownership and lifetime of the objects.
Association has the loosest relationship, while composed objects die together.

For a complete description with examples, refer to [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).